# Has the armhf cross compilation repositories been removed?

Tags: 16.04, apt, arm

It seems that ubuntu forgot about the armhf packages? Am I missing something?

The issue can be recreated with this simple Dockerfile:

```
    FROM ubuntu
    USER root
    RUN dpkg --add-architecture armhf
    RUN apt-get update
```

But apparently the ubuntu repositories doesn't know about this?

```
    E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
    E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
    E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
    E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
    E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Assistance will be greatly appreciated

Comment: For cross-compilation, don't you want something like https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/crossbuild-essential-armhf? The arm repositories are on http://ports.ubuntu.com/, IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks! After some digging, I realise we need to patch the sources.list to include ports

```
    FROM ubuntu
    USER root
    RUN sed -i "s/^deb /deb \[arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture)] /" /etc/apt/sources.list
    RUN for SUFFIX in "" "-updates" "-security"; do \
      echo "deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial${SUFFIX} main restricted universe multiverse" \
      >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/armhf.list; \
    done
    RUN dpkg --add-architecture armhf
    RUN apt-get update
```

Note that I'm not quite sure of the origins of this script.